# SD card in Android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

In my app I have two buttons play and download. In the downlod button I download video from internet and store in SD card, i will play video from the SD card when press play button.

Video is successfully downloaded and stored in SD card. If I press play button, I will list videos from SD card(in `logcat`) and play the downloaded video. It does not show the downloaded video name, but if I open the SD card from my system the downloaded video is stored in SD card. i do not know where i am wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add media files to Media Store in order to be seen by gallery widget. Use MediaScanner. I use this convenient wrapper in my code:

```
public class MediaScannerWrapper implements  
MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient {
    private MediaScannerConnection mConnection;
    private String mPath;
    private String mMimeType;

    // filePath - where to scan; 
    // mime type of media to scan i.e. "image/jpeg". 
    // use "*/*" for any media
    public MediaScannerWrapper(Context ctx, String filePath, String mime){
        mPath = filePath;
        mMimeType = mime;
        mConnection = new MediaScannerConnection(ctx, this);
    }

    // do the scanning
    public void scan() {
        mConnection.connect();
    }

    // start the scan when scanner is ready
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mConnection.scanFile(mPath, mMimeType);
        Log.w("MediaScannerWrapper", "media file scanned: " + mPath);
    }

    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        // when scan is completes, update media file tags
    }
}
```

Then instantiate `MediaScannerWrapper` and start it with `scan()`. You could tweak it to handle more than one file at the time. Hint: pass List of File paths, and then loop around `mConnection.scanFile`.