# Adding audio(wav file) to android Media Store

Tags: android, mediastore, android-mediascanner

I have an `Android` app that records and play audio. I have a problem with the recordings, they are not recognized immediately by the android default audio player(`Walkman` in my case). Also, the recordings are not seen by the Computer's explorer when I connect the phone to the PC. I should add each recording to the `Media Store`? If yes, how should I do this by not triggering a whole `SD` card scan, but only including the recording itself into the `Media Server` database?

I want to avoid if possible the line below because I think will trigger whole `SD` card to be scanned so this will drain the battery:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it. Grabbed some code from "[SD card in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482751/sd-card-in-android)"

```
new MediaScannerWrapper(ctx, mostRecentRecording.getFullPath(), "audio/*").scan();
ctx.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + PathsHandler.getInstance().getRecordingsDirectory())));
```

below is the MediaScannerWrapper which I took it from the post mentioned above:

```
public class MediaScannerWrapper implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {

     private MediaScannerConnection mConnection;
     private String mPath;
     private String mMimeType;

     public MediaScannerWrapper(Context ctx, String filePath, String mime){
         mPath = filePath;
         mMimeType = mime;
         mConnection = new MediaScannerConnection(ctx, this);
     }

     public void scan(){
         mConnection.connect();
     }

    @Override
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mConnection.scanFile(mPath, mMimeType);
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Media file scanned: "+mPath);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String arg0, Uri arg1) {
    }

}
```